# kendo ui scheduler not display new entries

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, scheduler

I'm just starting out with Kendo UI and Angular and am trying to use the Scheduler with a SQL database. The problem is when a new entry is added into the scheduler, I can see that the entry is initially created in the UI (behind the new Event window) , but when "Save" is clicked on the Event its successfully saved in the database but the entry is no longer in the UI and the only way I can see of getting it shown is to do a reload of the data which loses the current view settings.

Am I doing/not doing something stupid or is there a method to show the new event without doing a another full read of the data?

```
     var schedSource =   new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
    schema: {
        model: {
            id:"taskId", 
            fields: {
                    taskId: {
                    from: "id", 
                    type: "number"
                },
                start: { type: "date", from: "start" },
                end: { type: "date", from: "end" },
                title: { from: "title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
            }
        }
    },
        transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/sched',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        },
        update : {
            url: '/sched/update',
            dataType: 'json'
        },
         create: {
            url: '/schedCreate',
            dataType: "json"
       },
        destroy: {
            url: '/schedDelete',
            dataType: "json"
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation != "read") {
              var d = new Date(options.start);
              options.start = kendo.toString(new Date(d), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
              console.log(options.start);
              var d = new Date(options.end);
              options.end = kendo.toString(new Date(d), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");                           
            }

        },
    },

 });
 $scope.schOptions.dataSource = schedSource;
```

using k-options for the scheduler

```
<body ng-controller="schedulCtrl">
<div kendo-scheduler k-date="today" k-options="schOptions"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: is your create handler on the server returning the created model?

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for the response. Yeah it is. I've just worked around it now by capturing the save event then using that within Sync to do a datasource.read. not sure if that's the best way of doing it but appears to work okay

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is listed in the Scheduler troubleshooting help article (the reason is that the service is not returning the created record):

- [Create/Destroy/Update Request Is Sent Multiple Times to the Remote Service](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/troubleshoot/troubleshooting#createdestroyupdate-request-is-sent-multiple-times-to-the-remote-service)